# this.bajar() is not a function

Tags: javascript, class, oop, this

I have the following code:

```
subir() {
    this.y -= 5;
    if(this.y <= 2) {
        clearInterval(this.salto);
        this.salto = setInterval("this.bajar()", this.vel);
    }
}
bajar() {
    this.y += 5;
    if(this.y >= 15){
        this.saltar = true;
        clearInterval(this.salto);
    }
}
```

These functions are inside a `class` named Dinosaurio. When I call `subir()` it works fine, and as you saw in the code, it should automatically call the `bajar()` function after a few seconds. But `bajar()` doesn't work, and instead I got in the console `this.bajar() is not a function`

What is causing this bug?

Comment: I forgot to tell you, I call the "subir()" function from a "setinterval" that is stored inside "this.salto"

Comment: Take the qutoes away from `this.bajar()` and lose the parenthesis. The syntax should be `this.bajar`. But secondly, the `this` object reference doesn't work like you think it does. You are not pointing to the correct object. Just call `bajar` instead.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That won't work either -- it needs to be `this.bajar.bind(this)`

Comment: You posted half the code. Always post a runnable example that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `this` keyword with `bind()` in `setInterval`, otherwise `this` will be treated as `window` object. Also remove the quotes.

Try like this,

```
this.salto = setInterval(this.bajar.bind(this), this.vel);
```

Note: When you use this, it refers to the context it's being used. So if you use inside the object, it will refer the same object. setInterval is shorthand if window.setInterval and when the callback passed to the setInterval is called, the context is changed to window object. So this refers to the window object. Hence, we have to use the bond method by passing this to bind the context to the current object. So bind will return new method with the same context.

Comment: Typo corrected.

Comment: I think you need to take out the quotes.

Comment: Yes are correct and updated

Comment: This is a solution without a good explanation of the problem, it doesn't help the user understand how `this` is bound in JavaScript

Comment: When you use this, it refers to the context it's being used. So if you use inside the object, it will refer the same object. setInterval is shorthand if window.setInterval and when the callback passed to the setInterval is called, the context is changed to window object. So this refers to the window object. Hence, we have to use the bond method by passing this to bind the context to the current object. So bind will return new method with the same context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just try with "bind" it didn't work, I got the same error: "this.bajar" is not a function

Comment: Can you place the full code, I mean with the class and other required piece. I will fix it.

Comment: @giovanni look at the answer I posted a link to, it explains all details of how `this` works